# Rails4, How to config multiple model on sorcery Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, sorcery

I change User model to normal_user and admin_user

And I wanna authenticate both user on web

My plan is **normal_user only using web page and admin_user only using admin or client page**

below sorcery config file is support only one Model.

```
config.user_class = "User"
```

But I wanna  suport User and AdminUser.

How to config file or another solution setting multiple authencatin user?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in Application controller (Module: Admin )

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.user_class = Admin
```

or without module inside default application controller

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.user_class = User
```

Perhaps it will help you.